# How to group and subgroup and get data from a linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

Hi. I have three tables and I am trying to get group them and subgroup as well.

```
Table Sections
-------------
Id
SectionName


Table Categories
-------------
Id 
CategoryName
SectionRefId


Table Records
-------------
Id
RecordName
CategoryRefId
```

What I am trying to achieve is to group all Category by SectionName and group all Records by CategoryName and display them using a foreach loop.

```
I tried this using Linkpad the result it not what i exptected </p>


var result = from doc in Categories
             group doc by doc.SectionRefId into docSections
             select new  
             {
                Name = docSections.Key,
                Group = from dl in Records
                        group dl by dl.CategoryRefId into dlRecords
                        select new 
                        {
                            Name = dlRecords.Key,
                            GroupRecords = dlocation
                        }
             };


enter code here
```

Comment: Do you have any sql query for the same?

Comment: No sql query, I am trying to figure it out only using linq. trying the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. Need to some joins and group by:

```
var result = from category in Categories
             join section in Sections on category.Id equals section.ID
             join record in Records on category.Id equals record.CategoryRefId
             group category by {section.SectionName} into g
             group record by {category.categoryName} into p
             select new { CategoryName = g.Key.CategoryName, SectionName = section.SectionName, RecordName = record.RecordName };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've followed the [entity framework code first conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx), your classes will have `virtual ICollection<...>` properties that will do the grouping for you:

```
class Section
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SectionName { get; set; }

    // every section has zero or more Categories (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories {get; set;}
}

class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    // every Category belongs to exactly one Section using foreign key:
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Section Section {get; set;}

    // every Category has zero or more Records (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Record> Records {get; set;}
}

class Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RecordName { get; set; }

    // every Record belongs to exactly one Category
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category {get; set;}
}
```

> In entity framework the columns of the database tables are represented
>   by the non-virtual properties. The virtual properties represent the
>   relations between the tables

Note, it might be that you've got different identifiers for your tables and columns, the main thing is that you added the virtual properties

> I am trying to achieve is to group all Category by SectionName and group all Records by CategoryName and display them using a foreach loop.

```
var results = myDbContext.Sections
    .Where (section => ...)             // only if you don't want all Sections
    .Select(section => new
    {
        // select only the properties you plan to use:
        Id = section.Id,
        Name = section.SectionName,

        // This section has zero or more categories:
        Categories = section.Categories
           .Where(category => ...)          // only if you don't want all categories
           .Select(category => new
           {
               // again, select only the properties you plan to use:
               Id = category.Id,
               ...
               // not needed, you already know the value:
               // SectionId = category.SectionId,

               // this category has zero or more Records:
               // you know the drill by now
               Records = category.Records
                  .Where(record => ...)   
                  .Select(record => new
                  {
                      Id = record.Id,
                      ...
                  })
                  .ToList(),
           })
           .ToList(),
     });
```

Entity framework knows your one-to-many relations and will do the proper GroupJoins for you